# Max Width not working for mobile view, I still get the desktop site version

Tags: android, html, css

can someone please open the site www.abeautiful.vision and let me know why the max width media in css is not working? Is it because the mobile opens the desktop version of the site? How do I overcome this? Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

to my html.

Remember to do this guys!